# Connecting inserting data to sqlite db using Java

Tags: java, sqlite, connection, sql-insert

I am newbie at Java. Currently I am trying to connect my Java program to Sqlite database I have created. I successfully connected it but for some reason I can't insert data into my table, I keep on having an error message : java.lang.NullPointerException. I am not sure it is because I have declared conn, s and rs as null. Can anyone help me please, I have attached an image of my code. Thanks.

```
Connection c =null;
      Statement s = null;
      ResultSet rs = null;

      try{  
     Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
     c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:dbUrl");
     c.setAutoCommit(false);
     s = c.createStatement();
     int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
     String Forename = (jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
     String Surname = (jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());

     String sql_insert = "insert into try (Forename, Surname) values ('"+Forename+"', '"+Surname+"')";
     s.executeUpdate(sql_insert);
     rs.close();
     s.close();
     c.commit();
     c.close();


     }catch(Exception e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. It's very annoying for us if we want to do things like paste the code into an IDE. Instead, paste the code into the question, highlight the code, and use CTRL + k or the `{}` button at the top to format it as a code block in the question. Make sure it's separated from the rest of the question by an empty line.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have changed it :)